# Getfem++ is installed on Ubuntu 18.04, but it is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, ubuntu-18.04

I installed Python GetFEM++ using these two lines in Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-getfem++
```

Then I started writing my code on Anaconda,

```
import getfem
m = mesh('cartesian', range(0, 3), range(0,3))
```

I got this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-7f9e03c41e63> in <module>
      1 import getfem
----> 2 m = mesh('cartesian', range(0, 3), range(0,3))

NameError: name 'mesh' is not defined
```

What should I do? Is it necessary to update Ubuntu 18.04 or install other packages?

Answer (score 0):

It should either be

```
import getfem
m = getfem.Mesh('cartesian', range(0, 3), range(0,3))
```

or

```
import getfem as gf
m = gf.Mesh('cartesian', range(0, 3), range(0,3))
```